# Django: correct values in request.POST but cannot save form

Tags: python, django

In my SignUp page I've 2 forms UserForm and Profile Form.

Profile Form relies in Profile model, that has a OneToOneField to the User model -default User model from Django-.

The idea is that when a User is created, a Profile for this user is also created:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**Profile model:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    #phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    shipping_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_district = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name) + "'s profile"
```

**Problem:** UserForm.is_valid() is `True`, but Profile_Form.is_valid() is `False`.

But in my request, I'm getting all the right values for ProfileForm:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['91sJC01vyty3Z9ECjrSop1bouUOF2ZeC9m6XZUgk0nTEH7p6W0DmtuQaB4EBhV22'], 'first_name': ['Juana'], 'last_name': ['Juana'], 'username': ['juana
juana'], 'dni': ['454545'], 'email': ['juana@gmail.com'], 'password1': ['caballo123'], 'password2': ['caballo123'], 'shipping_address1': ['Urb. La Merced Mz.G Lot.32'], 'ship
ping_address2': ['Villa FAP - San Roque'], 'shipping_department': ['Cajamarca'], 'shipping_province': ['Cajamarca'], 'shipping_district': ['Cajamarca']}>
```

**How to save correctly the ProfileForm?**

View that displays the UserForm and the ProfileForm:

```
@transaction.atomic
def signupView(request):
    peru = Peru.objects.all()
    department_list = set()
    province_list = set()
    district_list = set()
    for p in peru:
        department_list.add(p.departamento)
    department_list = list(department_list)
    print("Department List: ", department_list)
    if len(department_list):
        province_list = set(Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0]).values_list("provincia", flat=True))
        print("Provice List: ", province_list)
        province_list = list(province_list)
        # print("dfsfs", province_list)
    else:
        province_list = set()
    if len(province_list):
        district_list = set(
            Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0], provincia=province_list[0]).values_list("distrito",
                                                                                                         flat=True))
        print("district List: ", district_list)
    else:
        district_list = set()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST)
        print("This is Profile Form: ", profile_form)
        print("Is Profile_Form valid: ", profile_form.is_valid())
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Clientes')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
            raw_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.refresh_from_db()  # This will load the Profile created by the Signal
            # print(user_form.cleaned_data)
            print("Form is valid: district_list, province_list, department_list")
            print(district_list, province_list, department_list)
            profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST,
                                       instance=user.profile)  # Reload the profile form with the profile instance
            profile_form.full_clean()  # Manually clean the form this time. It is implicitly called by "is_valid()" method
            # print(profile_form.cleaned_data)
            profile_form.save()  # Gracefully save the form

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
    else:
        print("INVALID FORM")
        user_form = SignUpForm()

        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list)
        print('end of profile postdata print')
        print(profile_form)
        print("Profile Data:")

    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

This line returns false:

```
print("Is Profile_Form valid: ", profile_form.is_valid())
```

**ProfileForm**:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, district_list, province_list, department_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['shipping_district'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in district_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_province'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in province_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_department'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in department_list]))

    dni = forms.CharField(label='DNI', max_length=100, required=True)
    shipping_address1 = forms.CharField(label='Dirección de envío', max_length=100, required=True)
    shipping_address2 = forms.CharField(label='Dirección de envío 2 (opcional)', max_length=100, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('dni', 'shipping_address1',
                  'shipping_address2', 'shipping_department', 'shipping_province', 'shipping_district')
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
    else:
        print("INVALID User_FORM")
        print(user_form.errors)
        print("INVALID Profile_FORM")
        print(profile_form.errors)


INVALID User_Form

INVALID Profile_Form
<ul class="errorlist"><li>shipping_province<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. Tarata is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li><li>shipping_district<ul
 class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. Estique is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
[25/Jan/2019 18:18:38] "POST /account/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16522
[25/Jan/2019 18:18:38] "GET /static/css/footer.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1767
```

Answer (score 1):

Choices fields in forms do not expect a list of values. You will have several options, but the field will have only one value.

So, try this:

```
 profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
```

and compute the values for `shipping_district`, `shipping_province` and `shipping_department` as part `__init__` in your form.

### Update:

if order to see errors change your code:

```
user_form_valid =  user_form.is_valid()
profile_form_valid = profile_form.is_valid()

if user_form_valid and profile_form_valid:
    # ...
else:
    # print(user_form.errors)
    # print(profile_form.errors)
    # ...
```

### Update #2

The choices are not the same in the form you're presenting to the user are the one you're binding in your view, try to initialize try to find a way to initialize those choices the same values for every `ProfileForm` you instantiate.

On the other hand, I encourage you to use [FormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/) for this kind of situations.

Comment: Using: `profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)` returns `__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'province_list' and 'department_list'`

Comment: What I'm saying is in your constructor you're setting the options of such fields, not the value.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But I how to pass `shipping_district`, `shipping_province` and `shipping_department` as part of  POST? i need to put inside `ProfileForm(shipping_deparment = request.POST.get('shipping_deparment'),
shipping_province = request.POST.get('shipping_province'), shipping_district = request.POST.get('shipping_district'), request.POST)`??

Comment: What's the value of `form.errors` after `form.is_valid`?

Comment: Cannot access that part becuase of: 

`if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():` since `profile_form` is not valid, I cannot pass that conditional. please, see more details in my code, and tell me where should I call `form.errors`.

Comment: Answer edited to show how to access form errors in your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187345/discussion-between-raydel-miranda-and-omar-gonzales).